# Randomize a number in C within a range

Tags: c

I want to create a program to randomize a value number to generate the number 2 or 4 only!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int a = 0;
    while (a != 2 || a != 4) {
        a = rand() % 5;
    }
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work... I need something simpler. Any help?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your code, especially the loop condition. If `a != 2` is true (which it is on the first time), then what is the result of a logical OR operation with `true`? It might be simpler to understand if you reverse the condition, because then it would be `a == 2 && a == 4`, which doesn't really make much sense (how can `a` be equal to `2` *and* equal to `4` at the same time).

Comment: How about `(rand() % 2 + 1) * 2`?

Answer (score 2):

`a != 2 || a != 4` is always `1` since `a` cannot be 2 or 4 at the same time. Hence the loop is infinite.

From a statistical perspective this needs thought. Sampling and rejecting out of range values can tie you to a particular class of generators, so is best avoided if at all possible.

In the search for an alternative note that `rand()` typically alternates between odd and even numbers due to how it works internally! So doing something with the least significant bit (which is often mooted as an answer) is a bad idea indeed.

One approach is to remove the loop entirely and use

```
a = rand() < RAND_MAX / 2 ? 2 : 4;
```

which might introduce a slight statistical bias, but probably no worse than `rand` itself.

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is odd and evenly distributed, the distribution of `a` should be exactly 50/50.

Comment: @chqrlie: Once you hit the generator's periodicity, and probably many times before that, yes.

Comment: Why not get rid of the branch - e.g. `a = (rand() & 2) + 2;`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code didn't work because your while condition

```
a!=2 || a!=4
!(a==2&&a==4)  //a cannot be 2 and 4 at once.
!((0&&1)||(1&&0))
!(0||0)
!(0)
1
```

is always true.

Now coming to your approach, it is a correct approach, but not the best.
The correct code for your approach would be

```
while(a!=2 && a!=4)
```

I said not the best because statistically your algorithm would take approximately 4 random numbers before giving a 2 or 4 random output.
You could just use

```
int a  = 2+2*(rand() % 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes a pretty even distribution of 2s and 4s with the expression `int a = 2 * ((rand() % 2) + 1);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int twos = 0;
    int fours = 0;

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<2000; ++i)
    {
        int a = 2 * ((rand() % 2) + 1);
        (a == 2)? twos++ : fours++;
    }

    printf("2s: %d\n", twos);
    printf("4s: %d", fours);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4548KB
2s: 1005
4s: 995


Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4412KB
2s: 1022
4s: 978
```